# Get Homebrew to re-create executable symlinks for an installed package (ghostscript)?

Tags: terminal, homebrew, symlink

I am trying to re-install/re-link Ghostscript from Homebrew.  I previously had it installed from Hombrew and working fine, but recently I installed MacTeX 2023, and it seems that it replaced the symlinks in `/usr/local/bin` to Homebrew’s Ghostscript executables with symlinks to MacTeX’s Ghostscript, which is an older version.  So Homebrew’s `ghostscript` package is still installed, and its executables are present in `/usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript`, but they are not symlinked into `/usr/local/bin` (or anywhere else on my `$PATH`).

**How do I get Homebrew to recreate these symlinks?**  I’ve tried `brew link ghostscript`, `brew reinstall ghostscript`; I’ve followed all the suggestions of `brew doctor`, run `brew update`, `brew upgrade`, and `brew unlink ghostscript`, and then tried `brew link ghostscript` again; everything seems to go fine, no errors or caveats reported, but the symlinks to Ghostscript’s executables are still not getting re-created.  Other Homebrew-installed executables are linked in `/usr/local/bin` as expected, including newly installed ones.

Comment: As far as I know, Homebrew doesn’t symlink into the system’s binaries folder.  You wouldn’t have two files named the same, but one being a binary and the other a symlink (i.e. a `gs` binary and a `gs` symlink).  More than likely, your path got modified and is now referencing the wrong directory *first*

Comment: @Allan `/usr/local/bin` is the folder Homebrew links to on Intel systems.

Comment: What does `type /usr/local/bin/gs` say?

Comment: Then why not force a reinstall of GhostScript.  That will recreate everything. @nohillside

Comment: @allan A reinstall will not overwrite existing files installed by other means unless you pass `--overwrite` as an option.

Comment: @nohillside: I don’t know what `type` would have said — at the start of this issue, `/usr/local/bin/gs` was a symlink to MacTeX’s `gs` executable, and one of the first things I did was deleting the symlink

Answer (score 2):

Homebrew doesn't overwrite existing files when linking (you should actually get a warning/error in that cases), but you can force it to link anyway:

```
brew link --overwrite ghostscript
```

Comment: Thankyou! Sadly this didn’t work, and didn’t report any warning either; running with `--verbose` showed `link` and `unlink` were only touching 1 link, which was in `doc`, nothing in `bin`. (And `reinstall` similarly.) In the end I solved the issue though — will write it up as an answer tomorrow when back at my office computer, didn’t have time before leaving work today.