# why the nginx have two path in macOS 13.2

Tags: macos, homebrew, open-source

Today I found the nginx have path `/opt/homebrew/opt/nginx` and `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/nginx` in the macOS 13.2, which one should I use? why the macOS have two different path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

macOS doesn't ship `nginx/brew`, so this is purely an implementation decision made by the architects of the homebrew software.

Typically the program installs several versions of each tool in the Cellar and then symbolically links the latest / chosen version in a place where your path allows calling of the tools.

Are you sure one isn't a [sym link and it's the same executable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/459965/5472)?